# unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'artifactory'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, bitbucket, artifactory

hy folks

i using artifactory without proxy .
When I run my pipeline from Bitbucket everything runs fine until it has to push the container to Jfrog
in bitbucket i've only this information

```
b3364fba5ee6: Retrying in 7 seconds
```

However when i go to Jfrog Artifactory and watch the log

**consol.log :**

```
[http-nio-8081-exec-5] - Unsupported docker v2 repository request for 'artifactory'
```

what is weird it's in my request.log file i've this :
**request.log :**

```
2021-04-30T01:57:06.369Z|353d90076bee8ad8|34.232.119.183|tech-gandallgroup|POST|/api/docker/artifactory/v2/docker-gandall/
test/blobs/uploads/|404|0|0|4|docker/19.03.15 go/go1.13.15 git-commit/99e3ed8 kernel/5.6.0 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient
(Docker-Client/19.03.15 \(linux\))
```

what is curious is that just after **blobs/uploads/** in the url I have a **404** .

Have you ever encountered this problem?
if so how did you solve it?

Bitbucket docker version : **19.03.15**

Jfrog Artifactory version : **7.11.5**

I m not using a proxy.